# PHP executing AND Being displayed as text

Tags: php

I have php on my site that creates search boxes for multiple sites. I just set up vhosts (Sub-Domains) and moved the search directory to it. after doing that the php now displays on the page, as well as executing successfuly. i don't know how it does both but it does. the code is all below:

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
if (isset($_GET['q'])){
 $query = $_GET['q'];
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=$query\">";
}

if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
 $yquery = $_GET['p'];
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://uk.search.yahoo.com/search?p=$yquery\">";
}

if (isset($_GET['yt'])) {
 $ytquery = $_GET['yt'];
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$ytquery\">";

}

if (isset($_GET['amz'])) {
 $amzquery = $_GET['amz'];
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/keywords=$amzquery\">";

}

if (isset($_GET['eby'])) {
 $ebyquery = $_GET['eby'];
 echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=http://www.amazon.co.uk/sch/i.html/_nkw=$ebyquery\">";

}
?>


<div id="searchForms">
<form id="gSearch" method="GET" action="http://www.google.co.uk/search"  />
<input type="text" name="q" placeholder="Google UK" value='' />
<input type="submit" value="Google Search"/>
</form>

<form id="ySearch" method="GET" action="http://uk.search.yahoo.com/search" />
<input type="text" name="p" placeholder="Yahoo" value='' />
<input type="submit" value="Yahoo Search"/>
</form>

<form id="ytSearch" method="GET" action="http://www.youtube.com/results" />
<input type="text" name="search_query" placeholder="YouTube" value='' />
<input type="submit" value="YouTube Search"/>
</form>

<form id="ebySearch" method="GET" action="http://www.EBay.co.uk/sch/i.html" />
<input type="text" name="_nkw" placeholder="EBay" value='' />
<input type="submit" value="EBay Search"/>
</form>

<form id="amzSearch" method="GET" action="http://www.amazon.co.uk/s/" />
<input type="text" name="keywords" placeholder="Amazon" value='' />
<input type="submit" value="Amazon Search"/>
</form>


</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's *not* doing both.  The PHP is not being ran.  The browser sees the PHP file's source as an HTML file.  The browser doesn't know what PHP is, it sees the HTML tags and tries to render them.  View the source of your page and you'll see *exactly* what's going on.

Comment: Is the file executable?

Comment: @user2393256: since when do php scripts have to be executable? That's only relevant if you're trying to run them as a shell script at a shell prompt.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the code is still working, as in the search boxes still work. hence it is somewhat working. I don't know why it is doing what it is though. :/

Comment: Given a Down vote..... Your forms are using an action urls Then Why are you using isset ?

Comment: currently there is no formatting, as i am first going for pure functionality. You can view the page [here](http://search.my-coding.com) if you wish.

Comment: @Indra thank you just realized i don't need any php. I am so dumb. you totaly are the best!

Answer (score 0):

This is not what you search for, but it better to use

```
header('Location: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q='.quotemeta($query));
```

and switch/case...

And very important is, check you input to security-patterns. [The Open Web Application Security Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP is not nescassery and is actually doing nothing to the search boxes. Everything betweeen  `<?php` and `?>` can and should be removed, since the action attribute of the forms are doing the redirecting already.